# Temperature and correlation with evaporation

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, phase-transition, evaporation

If as water evaporates it carries energy with it and therefore there is a reduction in temperature, why does the temperature remain constant in the phase transition between liquid water  and gas water?

Comment: The temperature doesn’t remain constant in the absence of external heating. Please clarify the premise; who is claiming that the temperature always remains constant?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, there is no reason that the temperature should remain constant as water evaporates unless it is supplied with some source of heat. In fact, since the enthalpy of the reaction that converts liquid water to its vapor phase is quite positive (about 40 kJ/mol), then at a constant external pressure the water must be losing heat to evaporate! But when sufficient heat is supplied, the temperature will not drop. The reason the temperature is fixed at the phase transition is because the vapor pressure in an external atmosphere fixed at 1 atm cannot ever exceed 1 atm unless the equilibrium between the liquid and vapor phases is broken (I.e. the water fully boils off). There is, of course, an equilibrium that is established between the liquid and vapor phases at any particular temperature with some characteristic (usually small) vapor pressure. At room temperature the vapor pressure of water is only 0.03 atm, so this checks out.